# Go to place in mapbox by url

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to build an aplication that allows users to share their current view of the map Using Mapbox GL-JS. I have heard about something called hash in the API docs but I am not sure how to implement it. I was looking for something like this: https://example.com?pos=-X,Y

Comment: I suggest you look at examples - mabbox provides many of them. What you need is an event handler that can get the coordinates. The rest is just code; you need to find a way to define interest points or areas and determine the point with closest proximity or which area a click is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is for the map to initialise at a location depending on the URL, you can achieve this by initialising the map with:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   // ...
   // hash: true
});
```

When you move the map around, the URL will update, something like `localhost:8000/#15/-144.9,-37.8`.

If this wasn't what you were asking, I suggest putting more details in your question.

Comment: Yep that is what I am looking for! thanks a bunch